# SQL: How to join when multiple columns point to the same other table?

Tags: sql, database, select, join, multiple-tables

Well lets say I have a Message entity that has field Sender and Recipient, both are stored in database by the foreign key of User entity. The table structure for message table may look like this:

```
id int(11) Not Null primary, autoincrement
sender int(11) Not Null
recipient int(11) Not Null
title varchar(50) Not Null
content varchar(1000) Not Null
datesent datetime Not Null
status varchar(10) Not Null
```

As you see, the message table has two foreign keys(sender and recipient) and both point to the same user table. Of course I can choose lazy load, thus do not write a join query and instead write two separate queries to load users for sender and recipient separately. It works fine if I am just loading one Message from table, but it can be a significant performance hit when you view a list of messages.

So how can I write a SQL query that join message table with user table when I need both sender and recipient columns to be joined? Anyone know the trick to complete this task?

Comment: Join it two times with the user table. Hint, use aliases :)

Answer (score 0):

if i true undestand you question try join 'user' table twice with there ids
Example:

```
select * from Message m left join user se on se.id = m.sender_id 
left join user re on re.id = m.recipient_id
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
select m.*,s.username,r.username
from message m 
inner join user s on m.sender = s.userid
inner join user r on m.recipient = r.userid
```

If there are some senders who do not have any entry in `user` table, then use left join